# Como detectar se a página está rolando para baixo ou para cima?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso, em javascript.
Seria para um menu `fixed` no topo. Ele apareceria ao rolar o body para cima, e sumiria ao rolar para baixo, mas preciso detectar a direção do scroll com js.

Existe alguma função (genérica ou nativa) para que eu possa detectar isso?

Se não for incômodo, gostaria que fosse em JS puro, sem jQuery ou algo do tipo.